# Compiling blender ended in incomplete configuration

Tags: build, blender

I am trying to compile the blender sources and follow the instruction from here: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Linux/Generic_Distro/CMake

I am in the step "Automatic CMake Setup", but when I call "make" the compilation ended with the following result:

```
...
used as include directory in directory/home/miguellissimo/git/blender/intern/cycles/kernel
used as include directory in directory/home/miguellissimo/git/blender/intern/cycles/render
used as include directory in directory/home/miguellissimo/git/blender/intern/cycles/subd
used as include directory in directory/home/miguellissimo/git/blender/intern/cycles/util
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Does anybody know why it is not compiling?

Comment: Not enough there to see the error details. You can use something like pasteall.org to share longer text outputs. Do you have all dependencies installed? What system are you using?